# Regular language proving

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Question:The set of all first names given to children born in New Zealand in 1996

I think this language is regular because every element in the set can be a accept state

How can I prove if the language is regular?

Comment: It is a _finite_ set, thus regular.

Comment: also see http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/157

Answer (score 3):

Every finite language is regular. The easiest way to prove it is to build the regular expression $w_1+w_2+\dots+w_n$ where $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ is you finite language.

You can also build an automaton as you said. May be build a separate one  for each word and the do a finite union is the easiest.

Comment: Just in case: $+$ is also $|$ in regular expression notation.