# Pumping Lemma for regular language

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I have a question to find out that L = {a^(2k)|k>=1} is regular. I know that it is regular set but I was looking to find out if pumping lemma is satisfying or not. So I tried it as -

```
Let # of states in the FA be n & I select the string w = a^2n
Now let xyz = w
xy = a^n
y = a^m | m is odd number
now x(y^2)z = a^(n-m)(a^2m)(a^n) 
= a(2n+m) does not belong to L
```

which says this regular set doesn't satisfy pumping property. Please let me know if I am doing something wrongly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you read our reference questions, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1031/755.  With the methods there, you should be able to answer your question on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pumping lemma says that every (long-enough) string in a regular language can be divided in some way such that it can be pumped (subject to the other stated conditions).

Note that the statement is that every string *has at least one way* of dividing it up. Not every division of a string necessarily works. As you have shown, some don't work, however there is a different division (any one where $m$ is even) that does work. So the language does satisfy the pumping lemma.