# Describing explicitly the MyHill-Nerode classes created by a language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

I want to practice proving a language is regular or not using the MyHill-Nerode theorm, but for that I need to be able to describe the classes. Here's my practice attempt:

For the language
$$L=\{\omega \in \{a,b\}^* \colon \omega \text{ contains at most 1 } 'a' \}$$
The classes are
$$M_1=\{\omega \in b^*\}$$
$$M_2=\{\omega \in b^*ab^*\}$$
$$M_3=\{\omega \in b^*ab^*a(a\cup b)^*\}$$

Now, the way I understand it I need to prove 2 things:

1. For each $u,v\in M_i (1\le i\le 3)$ and for each $x\in \Sigma^*$
   $$ux\in L \iff vx\in L$$
2. There exists $u\in M_i,v\in M_j(1\le i \neq j \le 3)$ and $x\in \Sigma^*$ such that
   $$ux\in L,vx\notin L$$

Am I right about how I described the classes, and about how to prove it?

Comment: Actually, you need to prove a 3rd thing: that your equivalence classes form a partition of $\Sigma ^{*}$ .

Beside that, your EC are Ok, indeed you need 3 classes in this case

Comment: What research and reading have you done?  Have you studied the explanation of Myhill-Nerode in standard textbooks?  Have you looked at our reference questions on this topic?  e.g., http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755  Finally, "please check my answer" questions are not a good fit for this site.  Only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your classes are correct, and one can also describe them in words: words containing no $a$, words containing a single $a$, words containing at least two $a$s. When described in this fashion, it is clear that the every word belongs to exactly one class.

However, there is no reason to use the Myhill–Nerode criterion to prove that a language is regular. Instead, you can use its vast generalization and give a DFA or NFA for the language. In the other direction, there is no need to describe *all* classes, only infinitely many; this already shows the language is not regular.