# Generate Regular Grammar for a Language with Modular Condition

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, formal-grammars

This is a homework problem.  I've wrestled with it for quite awhile and can't come up with a valid solution.  The problem is:

Find a regular grammar that generates each of the following languages:
$$L = \{ w \in {a,b}^* \mid \text{na}(w) – \text{nb}(w) = 1 \mod 3 \} , $$

where $\text{na}(w)$ is the number of $a$s and $\text{nb}(w)$ the number of $b$'s occurring in $w$, respectively.

It seems as though a DFA can't accept this language since any difference of $a$'s and $b$'s resulting in 1 will be in the language, but that gives an infinite number of possibilities.

Any help pointing me in the right direction for this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: See [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/how-to-prove-a-language-is-regular) and many examples via [tag:formal-grammars+regular-languages].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: How many states do you need to keep track of $n_a(w)-n_b(w) \pmod{3}$, where $w$ is any prefix of the input? Consider how many possibilities this quantity has, and whether knowing the value for a word $w$ helps you calculate the value for the word $w\alpha$ ($\alpha$ being a single symbol).

Comment: I'm thinking I need 3 states for mod3 since I can only have remainders 0,1,2.  From there, I don't quite follow.  Sorry, I'm new to this subject.

Comment: Right, you only need 3 states. You'll have to make the rest of the effort yourself. I won't answer any more questions. You're getting pretty close, and I'm sure you can finish solving the exercise on your own.

Comment: Ah, got it!  I thought -1mod3=1, but it's -2mod3=1.  That threw my DFA construction off.  Thank you for the help!