# How to understand DFA's and how to understand how to construct them based on a given regular language?

Tags: finite-automata, discrete-mathematics

I have practiced DFA's for an upcoming test and I haven't been able to grasp how to construct more difficult DFA's. An example would be this question :  Construct a deterministic finite state automata that recognizes the set of bit strings not containing 010 (With three states).

Comment: I can't actually see any of the answers to the linked question answering this one. That question says "How do I prove a language is regular" and answers "Construct a DFA". This question asks "How do I construct a DFA".

Comment: A question that has an accepted answer that shows how to "construct a deterministic finite state automata that recognizes the set of bit strings not containing 010" is [DFA for a strings whose every subsequence of length five has at least two zeroes](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/39960/91753).