# DFA Automaton with at least two 1s every four digits

Tags: finite-automata

How can I create a DFA automaton that will have every four digits (if they exist) at least two 1s for strings of languages with alphabet {0,1}?
The expression *at least two 1s* seems easier than the expression *every four digits*

Comment: Look at the solution by Rick Dekker for "[DFA for a strings whose every subsequence of length five has at least two zeroes](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/43759/4287)" where he explains that keeping a window of the most recently seen $k$ characters in the state can be used for DFA for languages of the form "All words over some alphabet $\Sigma$ where [some condition] is satisfied by all contiguous substrings of a fixed length, $k$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a DFA with 16 states, each corresponding to the last four letters possible.

For more details:

- the first three states will be special states with no turning back that will serve to count the number of $1$'s only in the three first letters;
- then you will navigate between states depending on the number of $1$'s read in the last four letters;
- each time you might reach a state describing zero or one $1$'s read in the last four letters, you can instead reach a non-final sink state that will loop on itself.

Comment: 16 states? How’s that come?

Comment: $16 = 2^4 = |\Sigma|^4$ is the number of words of length $4$.

Comment: One also needs a "fail" state for this idea, for 17 states total.

Comment: This, however, is not optimal. For instance, storing only the previous 3 letters is enough ($2^3 + 1 = 9$ states). In fact, the minimal DFA has 7 states.

Comment: @6005 Yes, you are right, I was only giving hints for the idea of the construction.

Comment: So, how can I combine both? Every four states there will be a state that will go back to the first with 1?

Comment: @wajaap I edited my answer.