# DFA for regular language

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

I need to construct a DFA which accepts the following language:
$$
L = \{w \in \{a,b\}^{\ast}\mid \#_{a}(w) \bmod 3 = \#_{b}(w) \bmod 2\}
$$
I have no clue how to solve this issue. Can you please help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? How would you go about writing a boolean function accepting it in a normal programming language?

Comment: Start with a simpler problem. For instance:  $L = \{w \mid w \in \Sigma^{*} ∧ \#a(w)\mod 2 = \#b(w) \mod 2\}$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove a language is regular?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/how-to-prove-a-language-is-regular)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Keep track of $\#_a(w) \pmod{3}$ and $\#_b(w) \pmod{2}$, using $3\times 2$ states.

Comment: By the way, the result can be generalized for any finite number of symbols, and any combination of congruence classes.