# how to make a regex that don't accept bab

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

hi how to make regex and 'DFA' to don't accept this 'bab' on this alphabet = {a,b}
and accept all language except 'bab'

Comment: That's a routine question with a routine answer. Please solve it on your own.

Comment: See [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755), and [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45570/755).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: For the DFA, first construct a DFA that will accept 'bab'. Then make final states into non-final states and vice versa. All you have to do is to think about error states. Finally, you might want to find the Regex from the DFA. Hint: [How to convert finite automata to regular expressions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions).