# Regular expression for string with substring 010 and ending with 01

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

How can one design a regular expression for given string in title ?

Also how can we draw DFA of that regular expression?

I've tried many expressions but couldn't succeed, please help.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45570/755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression would be like $(0 + 1)^*010(0 + 1)^*01 + (0 + 1)^*0101$.
Transformation of a regular expression to a DFA has a well-defined algorihtms, and you can find them in the resources.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Not the best photo quality , but it will work. I think this DFA is the one but correct me if i'm wrong. :)