# Define a finite automaton accepting the language below

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

$\{ w∈(a,b)^\ast | w $ does not contain '$ab$' as a subword $\}$.

About questions like this, I always want to construct the regular expression for it, then convert the regular expression to a finite automata. Is there an easier way? Actually, I dont know the regular expression of it either.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: This is a language where constructing the NFA directly is _probably_ simpler. Since the "language predicate" is a negation, it may be prudent to start with a _rejecting_ path, then fill in the accepting rest.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45570/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755

Answer (score 1):

It helps to think of finite automata in terms of their states. That is, think of what should each state represent for designing a finite automaton. In fact, it helps to "be the automaton". For this problem, you could start like, Initially, we are at the "start" state, say **S1**. Now we see an **"a"**, what do we do? We have matched part of the ab substring, so we now need to check if we get a **"b"** next in line. So this state "waiting for a **"b"**" is a new state, say **S2**. Now at **S1**, we get a **"b"**. This doesn't change anything, we still haven't got an "a" so we continue to remain in **S1**, waiting for an **"a"** to match and move to **S2**. At **S2** if we get a **"b"**, we have an **"ab"** now, so I move to a new "matched **ab**" state, say **S3**. At **S2**, if we get an **"a"**, then we are still in the "matched **a**" state, and continue to wait for B. Try to think this way, and you shall probably find it easier to design automata, I found this intuition helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a finite automaton is that each state stands for a combination of following kinds of properties.

- properties of the whole string, which basically determine whether the string should be accepted or not.
- what are the last several letters of a string, which basically determine the transitions between the states when another character is appended to the string.

For the language in the question, the relevant properties are
$\quad$- whether the string contains $ab$
$\quad$- the last character of the string
So there are about $2\times 2 = 4$ states.
$\quad$ $q_{\epsilon}$: the empty string.
$\quad$ $q_{\text{no}, a}$: strings that do not contains $ab$, ending with $a$.
$\quad$ $q_{\text{no}, b}$: strings that do not contains $ab$, ending with $b$.
$\quad$ $q_{\text{yes}, a}$: strings that contain $ab$, ending with $a$.
$\quad$ $q_{\text{yes}, b}$: strings that contain $ab$, ending with $b$.
The last two states can be merged as one state
$\quad$ $q_{yes}$: strings that contain $ab$.

Note that meaningful subscripts are used to indicate the properties associated to the states. Upon seeing ${q}_{\text{no},a}$, you know immediately the input that reaches this state does not contain $ab$ and it ends with $a$.

**Exercise.** Define a finite automata that accepts the language $\{w\in\{a,b\}^*\mid w\text{ contains } b\text{ but does not contain } bba\text{ as a subword}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Can you construct a FA for the language of all strings over $\{\texttt{a}, \texttt{b}\}$ that *do* contain $\texttt{ab}$? Given a finite automaton that accepts a language $L$, can you construct a new FA that accepts the complement of $L$? If so, you have your answer.