# Generating regular expressions not containing abc

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

Let sigma = {a,b,c}. How do I generate a language L that does not containg abc?
Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Should $L$ contain all words except abc? I.e., are you looking for a regular expression for $L = \Sigma^* \setminus \{ abc \}$?

Comment: Yes! So my L for now contains all words where aaa appears exactly once. But it also generates abc. And I need the L without abc.

Comment: I added an answer that shows how to obtain a regular expression for $L$. Anyway, the language associated to your regular expression does contain the word "abc"...

Comment: all words except $abc$, or all words that do not contain $abc$ [as a subword] ??

Comment: The latter. Sorry!

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45570/755

Answer (score 1):

Design a DFA that recognizes "abc" (make sure to include all transitions). Complement it (make accepting states non-accepting, and make non-accepting states accepting) in order to get a DFA for $L = \Sigma^* \setminus \{ abc \}$. Finally, [write down the regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550711/what-is-the-language-of-this-deterministic-finite-automata/13965717#13965717) of the complemented DFA.

---

As a brute force solution that does not use DFAs: write a regular expression for all words of lengths 0, 1, 2, and more than 3. This should be easy. 
Then write, a regular expression for all words of length 3 except abc.
For example:
$(b+c)(a+b+c)^2 + ab(a+b) + a(a+c)(a+b+c)$

Take the union of all the above REs.

Comment: Thank you. But it is only the beginning of the course and we haven't learned, therefore, I am not familiar with DFA :|

Comment: I edited my answer to add an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

The language of all words not containing $abc$ as a subword can be handled by focussing on the letter $b$.
Whenever it occurs in the string we should check that one of the following conditions hold:

- it is the first letter of the string
- it is directly after another $b$ or after a $c$,
  or symmetrically
- it is directly before ...
- it is the last letter of the string

If that is true, I think it can be handled efficiently with a regular expression.

Be safe, all!