# Regular expression for words without two equal consecutive letters

Tags: regular-expressions

I need to find a regular expression for the language over $\{a,b,c\}$ consisting of all words in which no two consecutive letters are the same.
For example, $abacbabca$ is in the language, while $abbc$ isn't.

How do I do that?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is really easy to come up with a DFA for your language. Then you can convert your DFA to a regular expression using [standard techniques](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions).

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45570/755

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a regular expression for all *non-empty* words over $\{a,b\}$ without $aa$ or $bb$. Such words must alternate $a$'s and $b$'s, making it easy to construct a regular expression for this language.

Now let's consider the language of all words over $\{a,b,c\}$ without $aa,bb,cc$. Such a word is either empty, or of the form $w_1 c w_2 c \cdots w_{n-1} c w_n$, where $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ are words over $\{a,b\}$ without $aa$ or $bb$, and furthermore $w_2,\ldots,w_{n-1}$ are non-empty. Using this description, you can easily construct a regular expression for your language using the regular expression constructed in the preceding paragraph.