# What is the regular language for L = {w | w has even length, and starts and ends with the same symbol}?

Tags: computability, regular-languages, finite-automata, context-free, regular-expressions

I **originally** thought it was 0(01)*(01)*0 U 1(01)*(01)1 where:

- two versions: one that starts and ends with 0, the other that starts and ends with 1
- connected by plus, which does not mean union of both but either or
- repeat of (01)* to make the string even. For example, for 0010 you would

1. start with 0
2. pick 0 from the first 01s
3. pick 0 from the second 01s
4. end with 0

**UPDATE: I think this is a more clear and accurate answer: L=(00+11+01+10)∗(00+11)**

- 00 + 11 +01 + 10: All possible options for an even length
- 00+ 11: 00 will match either 00 or 01 and 11 will match 11 or 10

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45570/755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect since $0011 \in (00+11+01+10)^∗(00+11)$ but $0011 \notin L$.
Assuming we only consider words over $\{0, 1\}$, the language is recognised by

$$1\big((0 + 1)(0 + 1)\big)^*1 + 0\big((0 + 1)(0 + 1)\big)^*0$$

and more generally for alphabet $\Sigma$

$$\bigcup_{c \in \Sigma} c(\Sigma\Sigma)^*c.$$