Formal regular expression equivalent for this programming regex
Consider these Regexes written in Julia (they should be equivalent in Python):
φ = Regex("(?:[X](I*)){$n,}(?:5|6{$m,}|\\\$)")
ζ = Regex("(?:[X](I*)){$n,}(?:[5](I*){$m,}|6{$m,}|\\\$)")

They operate on a language $\Sigma = \{X, I, 5, 6\}$. They find patterns that consist of

occurrences of $2, 3, 4, I$ (in any order) where total number of $2$s, $3$s and $4$s is at least $n$, as long as these occurrences end with a $m$ repetitions of character $5$ or $m$ repetitions of character $6$.

The difference between the first and second regex is that the first does not impose the condition that the sequence ends with more than $1$ repetitions of 5.
What are their equivalent regular expressions?

I don't understand what you are asking.  Please ask about only a single language/regexp at a time.  Can you give a self-contained specification of the language you are referring to, so we don't have to understand Julia/Python regex syntax?  Why do you write X,I,5,6 in one place but 2,3,4,I in another place?  What have you tried and what progress have you made? See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45570/755 for how to approach such tasks.

Why write [X] and [5] instead of just X and 5?

The first line should have 5{$n,} instead of 5.

You explanation is contradictory. 2, 3, and 4 do not occur. Do you mean [234] instead of [X]?

Contrary to your explanation, there is no conditional dependency between the two parts of the expressions. You can write textbook regular expressions for the parts and concatenate them.

Do you mean $\Sigma = {2,3,4,5,6,I}$?

I think this is what you are looking for: $I^*(2I^* + 3I^* + 4I^*)^n(2I^* + 3I^* + 4I^*)^*(5^m + 6^m)$
