# L = {w belongs to {0, 1} * ∣ w has at most three 0’s}. Why is this regular language?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

L = {w belongs to {0, 1}* ∣ w has at most three 0’s}. Why is this regular language?

According to pumping lemma, what I think is that....
Suppose $x$=$0^2$, $y$=$0^1$, $z$=$1^n$ ($w=xyz$=${0^2}{0^1}{1^n}$),  then if we pump $y$, we may have more than three $0$s. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the pumping lemma's statement. ​ ​

Comment: What do you mean?
As far as I know, pumping lemma is,
If $L$ is a regular language, there exists $n$ such that for any string $w$ in L and $|w|$>=$n$ we can write $w=xyz$ such that
1)$|xy|$<=$n$,
2)$|y|>=1$,
3)$w=xy^iz$ for all $i$>=0,

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange. Please read
http://cs.stackexchange.com/tour, if you have not yet done so. --- You are confusing an existential quantifier for a universal one. The pumping lemma states that there is a decomposition $xyz$ of the string such that you can pump $y$. But your are not free to chose it: that would require universal quantification (for all vs there is).

Comment: I do not quite understand. Do you mean that I cannot choose $y=0^1$?

Comment: Oh I think I understood. So if I choose $y=0^1$, I am just proving for this specific partition, but there may be some other partition that satisfy the pumping lemma.. Therefore, if there exists a single case that satisfy the pumping lemma, we say that this language $L$ is regular.. Am i correct?

Comment: No, we say the pumping lemma does not prove that the language is not regular. ​

Comment: @ Ricky Demer I understand that if a language doesn't satisfy pumping lemma, the language is not regular. Is it wrong?

Comment: To prove that $L$ is regular, consider that regular languages are closed under set difference. Try to think of two regular expressions, $L_1$ and $L_2$, such that $L = L_1 \setminus L_2$. Set intersection is another way of thinking about the problem.

Comment: Intuitively: you only need a constant amount of memory to count the 0s. Formally: develop an automaton that does the counting.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have said, the key is in the statement of the pumping lemma.

The key to understanding how to apply the pumping (and how not to as well) is paying close attention to the quantifiers ("for all" and "there exists") and the order they come in:

> **The Pumping Lemma for Regular Languages**
>
> If the language $L \subseteq \Sigma^{\ast}$ is regular, then ***there exists*** a constant $p \geq 1$ such that ***for every*** string $s \in L$ where $|s| \geq p$, ***there exists*** a division of $s = xyz$ such that:
>
> 1. $|xy| \leq p$,
> 2. $|y| \geq 1$, and
> 3. for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $s' = xy^{i}z \in L$.

So if you wanted to show that a language obeyed the pumping lemma (note that is would not prove that it's regular, there are non-regular languages that can also be pumped), you have to first determine the pumping length $p$, then look at every string $s \in L$ and show that *there is some way* that $s$ can be broken down so that it can be pumped according to the conditions.

So in your case, if we ignore that you don't know $p$, the mistake is showing that *one* way of breaking it up doesn't work. So assuming that the pumping length is at least $4$ (it is, but why...?), then the breakdown $x = 000$, $y = 1$, $z = 1^{n-1}$ can quite happily be pumped.

When this has settled in, it also shows how the proofs of non-regularity via the pumping lemma work. You just have to find one string, but you have to show that there is no workable breakdown for that string.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! So my conclusion to this problem is that, since there exists at least one case that satisfies the pumping lemma (the breakdown $x = 000$, $y = 1$, $z = 1^{n-1}$), I can say that the language L is indeed a regular language.. Correct?

Comment: Nearly - it means regularity of $L$ does not contradict the pumping lemma, so that you can *not* say that $L$ is *not* regular (recall that the main use of the pumping lemma is proving non-regularity). To prove that it actually *is* regular, you could construct a regular grammar, finite automaton, or regular expression.

Comment: @KlausDraeger Thanks. Have another question. What if I made up my breakdown as I did in the original question, and concluded that $L$ is not regular? How can someone tell me that I am wrong using the pumping lemma? I am sorry it is a silly question, but I want to fully understand the concept. Thanks again.

Comment: That is because the lemma only requires that there is *some* breakdown for which the pumping works; the existence of another breakdown for which it doesn't work is not a contradiction. So a proof of non-regularity would have the form "Let $xyz$ be any decomposition satisfying the conditions. The possible cases are (...). In each case, pumping takes us out of $L$".

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the pumping lemma to prove that a language is regular.

The pumping lemma can be used to prove that a language is *not* regular, but it doesn't let you prove that a language *is* regular.

(Why?  The pumping lemma says something like "If $L$ is regular then (stuff)."  If you prove that (stuff) is false, then you can conclude that $L$ is not regular; that follows from the contrapositive of the pumping lemma.  But if you prove that (stuff) is true, you can't conclude anything: $L$ might be regular, or it might not; the pumping lemma makes no promises.)

Instead, to prove that a language is regular, you should use the techniques described in  [How to prove a language is regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755)

Comment: Ok I understand you point. But still, what is wrong about my case shown above question? Because if I show it like that, I show that L is not regular

Comment: @Mansumen, I've elaborated in my answer to try to explain the error in your reasoning in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

We use the pumping lemma to prove that a determinate language is not regular.

If you want to prove that a determinate language $L$ is regular then you have to write a regular expression, draw a NFA or draw a DFA that denotes $L$.

For example I can say that $L=\{w \in \{0,1\}|$ $w$ has at most three 0's $\}$ is regular because I found the regular expression:

$RE$ = $1^*(0|\epsilon)1^*(0|\epsilon)1^*(0|\epsilon)1^*$

and $\mathscr{L}(RE)=L$