# Properties of language that can be enumerated in a finite amount of time with an enumerator?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability

Suppose an enumerator *E* can enumerate some language *L* in a finite amount of time (3 days, 3 hours, etc.). What properties does this language have?

My guess:

- *L* is finite, so *L* is a context-free language.
- Since *L* is a context-free language, L is also decidable
- Since *L* is decidable, *L* is also Turing-recognizable and co-Turing recognizable

My Questions:

- Is *L* also a regular language?
- A theorem says that:

> A language is Turing-recognizable iff some enumerator enumerates it

- Is there anything more or less we can say about *L*, compared to a Turing-recognizable language?

Comment: I suggest you read more about regular language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755.

Comment: Every finite language is regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language can be enumerated in finite time, then the language itself is finite. Almost all natural classes of languages include all finite languages: they're regular, context-free, decidable, recursively enumerable, co-RE, ...

I'm not sure what else you'd want to say about finite languages compared to RE languages. It's enough to say that the language is finite; for any property you might be interested in, it's usually very straightforward to prove that finite languages do or do not have that property.

Comment: Thank you! So the very least you could say is that it's decidable (and therefore RE, and co-RE)?