# How to demonstrate that a language is regular for k?

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata

I sort of need an explanation on how can I demonstrate that a language formed by strings that are multiples of k, is a regular language

I really dont know how

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755

Comment: You mean the language which accepts strings of length of a multiple of $k$?

Comment: What is the alphabet of your language?

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing the other answer, here is a *complete* classification of regular language of this sort.

> The language $\{ x \in \Sigma^* : |x| \in S \}$ is regular iff there exist $n \geq 0$ and $k \geq 1$ and sets $A \subseteq \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, $B \subseteq \{0,\ldots,k-1\}$ such that
>   $$ S = A \cup \{ n+ mk + r : m \geq 0, r \in B\}.$$

One direction follows from a direct construction (either a DFA or a regular expression), and the other from the pumping lemma (exercise) or Parikh's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you wish to demonstrate that $L = \{ w \in \Sigma^* \colon |w| = k, 2k, ...\}$ for some $k > 0$ is a regular language (correct me if I am wrong).

If that is the case, all you need to do is to construct a DFA $M$ such that $L(M) = L$:

[image: DFA]