# $a^{2n}$ where $n\geq1$ is not Regular using Pumping Lemma

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I'm having trouble understanding Pumping Lemma for $RL$ , i know that $0^{2n}$ is regular and we can design a FSM for it.
Here's my pumping Lemma statement

Let $p$ be the pumping length and my string is $0^{2p}$
1. $z=|0^{2p}|=> 2p > p $ (**Satisfied**)
2. $z=uvw$ such that $|uv|\geq p$, I'm choosing $|u|=n-p$ and $|v|=p$ so that $|uv|\geq p$ (**Satisfied**)
3.Now $u(v^i)w$, I choose $i=3$ then $|uvw|=2(n+p)$ which is even
 
But if $n=2$ then $|uvw|=2n+p$, how do i know if this could be even/odd?

Comment: You don't get to choose the partition $z = uvw$. The pumping lemma only guarantees that such a partition exists.

Comment: Haven't we had this or very similar languages a lot recently?

Comment: Title says "...not Regular using Pumping Lemma", the body text says "...i know that $0^{2n}$ is regular...", the question is not clear.

Comment: @fade what I meant was we could prove it is not regular but actually it is regular

Comment: Okay, I see your point. Please have a look at [this almost identical question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79801/proving-that-language-l-a2n-n-geq-1-is-regular/79805#79805) if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove that a language is regular by applying the pumping lemma.

Regular Languages are a subset of Languages that satisfy the pumping lemma. So you can only proof irregularity with the lemma. (By assuming that the language is regular and coming to a contradiction)

One way to show that a language is regular, is e.g. constructing a Regular Expression, NFA or DFA (all of these being equivalent).

Comment: There are other ways of proving that a language is regular, for example using closure properties.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you, I edited my answer.