# What's de minimum DFA that L recognizes?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

If a language L on Σ = {a, b, c}, such that L = {w | #a(w) is even and #b(w) is even and #c(w) is even and | w | is even}. Where #a(w) represents the quantity of a's in w and | w | is the length of the string w. How many states have the minimum DFA that recognizes L?

Help me please!

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?  Where did you get stuck?  Have you tried finding any DFA (not necessarily minimal)?  Can you solve any simpler version of the problem?  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  It looks like this can be answered using the techniques in https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755.

Comment: I suggest you read through the reference material that is linked and the advice I linked you to, then try to find a DFA for this problem.  If you're still stuck, try solving a simpler version of the problem, and edit the question to show your progress on the simpler versions of the problem.