# DFA for strings with number of 0's odd only in substring longer than 1

Tags: automata, finite-automata, subsequences

I'm trying to design and DFA that accept string with an odd number of 0`s, but counting only the ones within sub-strings with two or more 0.

So, for example, 011**000**, will be accepted since it has 4 0`s, but only three or them are inside a sub-string of two or more. But **000**1**000**, wont be accepted.

Comment: After processing any character, you go into a state that is a combination of (0, 1, 2 or more zeroes) x (even or odd number of zeroes counted)

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755

Answer (score -1):

I believe your language is not regular and if I'm not mistaken, the pumping lemma suffices:
Let us assume by contradiction your language is regular, thus it should hold all 3 conditions of the pumping lemma.

Let $w=0^{2p+1}111$, notice $w\in L$ because $2n$ is always even, thus by adding $1$ we have an odd number of $0$s.

Now let us take a simple example where $p=1$, but this should work for any $p$.

In this case, $p=1$, notice $|w|>p$, since $|w|=5$, essentially $w=000111$. In our case this means $y=0$ and because $|xy|\le 1$ and because $|y|>0$  where 1 is our pumping length this means $x=\epsilon$.

This leaves $z=0011$. However, for $i=2$, we receive: `000011` which is $y^2z \equiv 000011 $.

Then the number of 0s in your substring is now even, meaning $000011 \notin L$. 
Again, we can do this for any pumping length $p$ by simply pumping up or pumping down.

Thus there won't be a DFA/NFA for that. You can try using a TM.

For more information: [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).

Comment: Perhaps some of the data was missing, making the language hold the conditions of the pumping lemma, let me know =)

Comment: You cannot assume what $p$ is when using pumping lemma.

Comment: You're correct, thank you for your comment. However, for this is simply an example, I'll edit the answer to emphasize that. Regardless, for such a word, we could always then make the number of 0s be even using pumping.