# Regular expression for containing 010 as a subword

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I am studying for a test in computer science, and am encountering difficulties with regular expression. Here is example of a question I don't understand.

I managed to solve the following question:

> Give a regular expression for the language of all words over $\{a,b\}$ which contains one of $aa,bb$ as a subword.

My solution: 
$$(a ∪ b)^*(aa ∪ bb)^*(a ∪ b)^*.$$

I am having trouble with the following question:

> Give a regular expression for the language of all words over $\{0,1\}$ which contains $010$ as a subword.

Comment: L1 does not look right. All the words in L1 are such that "aa" or "bb" occurs as a substring, but not all words that satisfy the above property are in L1.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755

Comment: What do you mean by "subword"?

Answer (score 1):

In the first one, L1 = (a+b)*(aa+bb)(a+b)* not (a+b)(aa+bb)(a+b)* because in the second one, it is possible only to have one character of a or b and then we have to find the occurrence we need. Your L1 denies any word that does start with (aa+bb). It also forces all the words to start with a or b.

By the way, I use + for | and ∪.

So for the second one, it is in the same manner:

L1 = (0+1)*(010)(0+1)*

010 might occurs in the beginning, the middle or the end of the word.