# How to show that a language is regular

Tags: automata, regular-languages

I know that to show that a language is not regular, you are supposed to use the pumping lemma, but I cannot figure out how can I show that a language is regular.

How would I show that the following language is regular?

$$
L=\{0^k1^l∣k+l\geq20, \ k,l \in\ \ N\}
$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove a language is regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/how-to-prove-a-language-is-regular)

Comment: The pumping lemma is a necessary condition for a language to be regular. Therefore you cannot prove that a language $L$ is regular by showing that the pumping lemma holds on $L$.

Answer (score 3):

Pumping lemma doesn’t provide us with an *if and only if* condition for regularity. So, if a language doesn’t satisfy pumping lemma then it isn’t regular, but converse is not true. 
So, I don’t think we can use pumping lemma to show that a language is regular.

To show given language is regular, you can use Myhill-Nerode theorem, simply come up with a DFA/NFA or a regular expression, or use some closure properties.

For the given language, you can show its regularity using closure property of regular languages (intersection, to be precise): 
$0^*1^*$ is regular, and so is the $L_{\geq 20} = \{w : |w| \geq 20\}$. It’s quite easy to see that the given language is intersection of these two languages, and hence it is regular.