# Converting along regular expression to NFA

Tags: finite-automata, nondeterminism

I have the following regular expression for the set of all strings such that each block of five consecutive symbols contains exactly two 0's (consider the alphabet to be {0, 1}):

(0+1+ϵ)<sup>4</sup>+(11100+ϵ)r(0011100r)*(00111+ϵ)

r=11+(110+ϵ)s(0110s)*(011+ϵ)

s=(0+10)*(1+ϵ)

How should I convert this into an NFA? Please explain the steps behind it as well!

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/137007/755

Comment: It would be better for you to show more independence when doing your homework.

Comment: Where is your regular expression taken from?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus this regular was provided to me by my friend who is doing this assignment with me. And I have just asked a conceptual question regarding converting a regular expression to an NFA, which is something I cannot understand well. So, could you please answer my question?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13606/755

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the Berry-Sethi algorithm, constructing the [Glushkov's automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glushkov%27s_construction_algorithm).

However, for your problem, I'd consider constructing directly a DFA with $10 = \begin{pmatrix}5\\2\end{pmatrix}$ states corresponding to words of size 5 containing exactly two zeros, and a sink state (and maybe some other states for the begining of the reading).

The Glushkov's automaton on your regular expression will be very big.