# Regular Languages are closed under Scarne's Cut

Tags: regular-languages

This exercise come from Sipser (1.68).

In essence, show that if $A$ is regular, then $CUT(A) := \{yxz | xyz \in A\}$ is regular. I've managed to show that $B = \{yx | xyz \in A\}$ is regular. Furthermore, I've shown that $SUFFIX(A) = \{z | xz \in A\}$ is regular. My idea was to then say that $CUT(A)$ is precisely the concatenation of $B$ and $SUFFIX(A)$. However, the trouble I'm running into is that this operation will attach the "wrong" suffixes to a string. For instance, if $A$ is "strings in alphabetical order", then $bad$ will be in the concatenation of $B$ and $SUFFIX(A)$.

How can I complete this?

Comment: If you are not familiar with the guessing technique, please read the parts of [this answer of Yuval on how to prove a language is regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/88049/91753) that explains that technique.

Comment: How did you show that $\{yx \mid xyz \in A\}$ is regular? If you used a construction with automata it can probably be extended to include the suffix $z$?