# How to determine class of formal language in Chomsky Hierachy

Tags: formal-languages, automata, chomsky-hierarchy

I recently started learning about the chomsky hierarchy and I am preparing myself for an upcoming exam. Often there are tasks to specify the smallest classification of a given formal language. How does one safely find the smallest class the language is included in? Which criterias should one look for when doing so?

- $\{a^nb^mc^md^n\mid m,n\geqslant 1\}$
- $\{a^nb^mc^nd^m\mid m, n\geqslant 1\}$
- $\{a^nw\mid w\in\Sigma^*, n\geqslant 0\}$
- $\{(ab)^n(ba)^n\mid n\geqslant 0\}$

Comment: [How to prove a language is regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/how-to-prove-a-language-is-regular) 
[How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)
[How to prove that a language is context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free/)
[How to prove that a language is not context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-context-free)